# Why am I getting a "could not find a registered alias" error?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, alias

I am getting this error: `cy.wait()` could not find a registered alias for: @waiting. You have not aliased anything yet

```
describe('', () => {
  it('sign up page', () => {
    cy.visit('/#/register')
  });
  const {userName, email, password} = generateNum()
  it('username', function() {
    cy.get('[placeholder="Username"]').type(userName).then(response => ({...userName}))
  })
  it('email', () => {
    cy.get('[placeholder="Email"]').type(email).then(response => ({...email}))
  })
    **it('intercept_w8', () => {
      cy.intercept('POST', '/api/users/').as('waiting')**
    });
  it('password', () => {
    cy.get('[placeholder="Password"]').type(password).then(response => ({...password}))
    cy.get('.btn').should('contain.text', 'Sign in').click()
  })
    **it('wait', () => {
      cy.wait('@waiting')**
    });
  it('registered user is loged in', () => {
    cy.visit('/#/login')
  });
  it('RegisteredEmail', () => {
    cy.get('[placeholder="Email"]').type(email)
  });
  it('RegisteredPassword', () => {
    cy.get('[placeholder="Password"]').type(password+'{enter}')
  });
})
```

So cypress is starting to use the `it'registered user is loged in'` before the registration is finished. So I'm trying to use the cy.intercept before click() and after wait() to wait the registration and have this error:

```
cy.wait() could not find a registered alias for: @waiting.
```

This is were the click goes:

```
click
(xhr)POST --- /api/users
```

Comment: Those tests seem a bit too small. You can easily bundle them all together.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cypress clears the alias between tests.

[Aliases are reset before each test](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/variables-and-aliases#Aliases-are-reset-before-each-test)

> **Note:** all aliases are reset before each test. A common user mistake is to create aliases using the before hook. Such aliases work in the first test only!

Remove the (unnecessary) `it()` blocks. Why do you have them there?

Comment: Thx its help! About it() its just for learning to know where the problem is